# Case with 2 columns causing: "Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

So I'm trying to count a case statement with 2 columns. Basically I'm using 1 and NULL to do the count of each case. However, when I try and include the `AND` for the second column, like below, I get a warning:

```
SELECT
   COUNT
      (CASE WHEN 1.sample IN ('a','b','c')
            AND  2.sample IN ('d','e','f')
       THEN 1
       ELSE NULL
       END
      )   AS CASE
FROM table1 AS 1
INNER JOIN table2 AS 2
...
```

> Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET
>   operation.

Is it because of the `NULL`? How else then can I count the case? Thanks

Comment: It is warning not error

Comment: Does it really says `Error:`?

Comment: `SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF`

Comment: In this example you could change COUNT to SUM. The result will be the same and the warning will go away too.

Comment: @SeanLange the warning will go away if op uses `ELSE 0 END` (with SUM)

Comment: @Lamak ahh yes...my bad.

Comment: Warning didn't go away with the Sum and Else 0