# Count Case with 2 columns with the same values (Clarified)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Basically I want COUNT a CASE when values are present in 2 columns.

For example:

```
SELECT
   COUNT
      (CASE WHEN 1.sample AND 2.sample IN ('a','b','c')
       THEN 1
       ELSE NULL
       END
      )   AS CASE
FROM table1 AS 1
INNER JOIN table2 AS 2
...
```

Message:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '08:12.06' to data
>   type int. Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other
>   SET operation.

I get what's triggering the error, I just don't know a solution to count the case when values are present in both columns.

Comment: `1.sample` has to be compared to something.

Comment: @WEI_DBA well I basically want to count it only if those values are in both columns

Comment: Try this then, `1.sample IN ('a','b','c') AND 2.sample IN ('a','b','c')`

Comment: When I did that, I got an entirely new issue which they reported as a duplicate here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47316223/case-with-2-columns-causing-warning-null-value-is-eliminated-by-an-aggregate

Comment: Though as you can see, it's not really a duplicate, I just didn't explain what I'm trying to achieve as good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this and see if it works? I think this is what you are looking for.

```
SELECT
   SUM
      (CASE WHEN 1.sample IN ('a','b','c') AND 2.sample IN ('a','b','c')
       THEN 1
       ELSE 0
       END
      )   AS CASE
FROM table1 AS 1
INNER JOIN table2 AS 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to list the columns separately for comparison. Usually I specify a column to count, and you do not need to put NULL for the else condition.

```
SELECT
   COUNT
      (CASE WHEN 1.sample IS NULL OR 2.sample IS NULL THEN 0 
            WHEN (    1.sample IN ('a','b','c')
                  AND 2.sample IN ('a','b','c')
                 )
       THEN 1.sample
       END
      )   AS CASE
FROM table1 AS 1
INNER JOIN table2 AS 2 ON....
```

Comment: When I did that, I got: `Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.`

Comment: Nope. I added the Message I'm getting .I think it has something to with one of the value types being pulled: `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '12:20.12' to data type int.
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.`